# Cannot log response and json after making a request using request-promise

Tags: node.js, request-promise

After making a request I am attempting to log both the response and json, however I can only log one at a time.

I have tried including response and json both in different functions, however one of them all-ways appeared as undefined depending on if they were in the first or second function (second was undefined)

```
function Example() {
  payload = {
    method: 'GET',
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    json: true,
    url: "https://www.example.com",
    headers: {
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive'
    },
    gzip: true
    }
     rp(payload)
      .then(function(response, json) { // in this case json is undefined however if I swap the code function(json, response) response becomes undefined
        console.log(response) // works
        console.log(json) // undefined
       }
   }
```

I am expecting both the response and json to print, instead of one printing undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the argument names do not mean anything and you can parse response as json.

Comment: Argument names never meant anything, they are only conventions. You could call your function `function fcn(randomArgument1)` and it would behave the exact same as `function fcn(someOtherArgumentName)`.